# Why does an array of objects behave differently when imported VS hard coded in a component?

Tags: reactjs, import, react-functional-component

Trying to stick with a workflow of hard coded data be an external file of reference in case I ever want to rely on an external source like an API. Given the current working component of:

```
const ExpensesChart = ({ expenses }) => {
  const chartDataPoints = [
    { label: 'Jan', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Feb', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Mar', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Apr', value: 0 },
    { label: 'May', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Jun', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Jul', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Aug', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Sep', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Oct', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Nov', value: 0 },
    { label: 'Dec', value: 0 },
  ]

  for (const expense of expenses) {
    const expenseMonth = expense.date.getMonth()
    chartDataPoints[expenseMonth].value += expense.amount
  }

  return <Child dataPoints={chartDataPoints} />
}

export default ExpensesChart
```

works without an issue. When I take the array of objects, `chartDataPoints`, and isolate it as a file reference and import the file the outcome is different when the data is passed down to `Child`:

chartData.js:

```
const chartDataPoints = [
  { label: 'Jan', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Feb', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Mar', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Apr', value: 0 },
  { label: 'May', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Jun', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Jul', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Aug', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Sep', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Oct', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Nov', value: 0 },
  { label: 'Dec', value: 0 },
]

export default chartDataPoints
```

re-written component:

```
// Data
import chartDataPoints from '../../data/chartData'

const ExpensesChart = ({ expenses }) => {
  for (const expense of expenses) {
    const expenseMonth = expense.date.getMonth()
    chartDataPoints[expenseMonth].value += expense.amount
  }

  return <Child dataPoints={chartDataPoints} />
}

export default ExpensesChart
```

I'm not seeing why or I should say not understanding why the behaviour is different. I assumed that when the props are different the entire component should be re-rendered there-for the for loop should re-run but the latter approach the data never changes. I dont see the need for a `useState` or `useEffect` if the for loop is modifying the data but I could be wrong.

Why does the array of objects behave differently from hard-coded VS imported in the component?

---

**Edit:**

Thinking differently here is an attempt with `useRef`, `useState`, `useEffect`:

```
const ExpensesChart = ({ expenses }) => {
  const data = useRef(chartData)
  const [chartPoints, setChartPoints] = useState(data.current)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (expenses.length === 0) return setChartPoints(data.current)

    for (const expense of expenses) {
      data.current[expense.date.getMonth()].value += expense.amount
    }
    return setChartPoints(data.current)
  }, [expenses])

  return <Chart dataPoints={chartPoints} />
}

export default ExpensesChart
```

But I still run into an issue. Also including a CodeSandBox:

[image: Code Sand Box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your re-written component, you're passing down the `expenses` as a prop *and mutating it*. Mutation should not be done in React, and it's causing you problems here - when you mutate the expenses due to one year, and then the component re-renders as a result of the year changing, you're passing down the *same mutated array* from earlier, so the changes persist.

When the year changes, initialize the new chart data from the initial empty array, and avoid mutating that initial array:

```
const ExpensesChart = ({ expenses }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(chartData);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Expenses just changed, so set the state
    // restarting from an empty chartData array
    const newData = chartData.map(obj => ({ ...obj }))
    for (const expense of expenses) {
      newData[expense.date.getMonth()].value += expense.amount;
    }
    setData(newData);
  }, [expenses]);
  return <Child { ... {data} } />;
};

export default ExpensesChart;
```

Comment: same issue exists. If I can find time I'll update with a codesandbox. FYI, `expenses` is an array that has been filtered in the parent component. So I'm thinking I may have to use `useState` and `useEffect`.

Comment: added sandbox and tried again.

Comment: Oh, so it's not that the component gets mounted elsewhere, or unmounted and re-mounted, but that the year changes during the same mount, which you're hoping should result in rendered changes. You definitely need state - when the year changes, take the *empty* array and populate it as needed, and set it as the new state.

Comment: Ya I thinks that best but for some reason when I try I keep running into an error. I thought useRef would work but it's not and I'm stumped.

Comment: One of the problems was you were splitting your data too much - best to have just *one* source, and pass it around. Since you want the display to depend on the stuff in the array, the array should be in state, not in a ref.

Comment: The code in the answer works - if you replace your ExpensesChart with it, you'll see how the chart values change (but do not persist) with the year, as desired.